# Find Instance with Set Membership Condition

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

Given two vectors $u=(x_1,\ldots,x_n,a_1,\ldots,a_s) \in \{-1,1\}^{n+s}$ and $v=(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in \{-1,1\}^n$ and a bunch of fixed vectors $c_1,\ldots,c_k \in \{-1,1\}^{n+s}$ and $b_1,\ldots,b_k \in \{-1,1\}^{n}$ and I want to find an instance when all the following (inner product) equations are satisfied:
$$c_i \cdot u + 1 = b_i \cdot v,\quad i=1,\ldots,s$$

In general $n$ will be large. So I want to specify the condition that I am only interested in solutions in, say, $\{-1,1\}^{n+s}$ by using the membership of $u$ in Tuples[{-1,1},n+s] instead of putting numerous componentwise integer inequalities into play after specifying Integers as a condition. I will want to do this for varying $n$ and $s.$

**Edit:** A small example, done componentwise is below. I want to abstract out the equations by using inner products since they will get messy for larger cases. Here $n=s=1$ and I ask for 4 instances. ff allows me to specify +1 and -1 by using ff[x,1].

```
ff[x_, a_] := (x^2 == a); 
FindInstance[
      x1*xn + 1 == a1*(x1 + xn) &&  ff[x1, 1] && ff[xn, 1] && 
      ff[a1, 1], {x1, xn, a1}, Integers, 4]
```

Comment: It would be useful to have a small example, in Mathematica input form.

Comment: Where is your  `b1`?

Comment: @belisariushassettled:For this case, it can be taken to be 1.

Comment: This example is nonlinear (it has products of variable `a1` by variables `x1` and `xn`). The description `c_i.u+1==b_i.v` is of a linear problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps

```
e = {-1, 1};
SeedRandom[42];
n = 3;
s = 3;
k = 2;
aa = Array[a, s];
vv = Array[x, n];
uu = Join[vv, aa];
c = RandomChoice[e, {k, n + s}];
b = RandomChoice[e, {k, n}];

FindInstance[And @@ MapThread[#1.uu + 1 == #2.vv &, {c, b}] && 
            (And @@    Thread[Abs[uu] == 1]), uu, Integers]

(*{{x[1] -> 1, x[2] -> 1, x[3] -> -1, a[1] -> 1, a[2] -> 1, a[3] -> 1}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you, your MapThread and Thread commands show me how to do this.

Comment: No, no, no. This is not going to scale.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I know. But `n will be large` doesn't set a scale either

Comment: What I meant by "to scale" was not "to the scale of the original question" but rather "to scale well on larger problems". I basically cribbed all your work, and made a minor tweak at the end, to get a method that will scale better.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slight adjustment to the method proposed by @Dr.belisarius. I'll show with a larger set of variables though.

```
e = {-1, 1};
SeedRandom[42];
n = 11;
s = 11;
k = 2;
aa = Array[a, s];
vv = Array[x, n];
uu = Join[vv, aa];
c = RandomChoice[e, {k, n + s}];
b = RandomChoice[e, {k, n}];
```

Now just adjust so these are 0-1 variables, multiply each by 2 and subtract 1 to get the effect of being +-1.

```
soln = 
 FindInstance[
  And @@ MapThread[#1.(2*uu - 1) + 1 == #2.(2*vv - 1) &, {c, 
      b}] && (And @@ Thread[0 <= uu <= 1]), uu, Integers]

(* Out[285]= {{x[1] -> 1, x[2] -> 0, x[3] -> 0, x[4] -> 0, x[5] -> 1, 
  x[6] -> 0, x[7] -> 0, x[8] -> 1, x[9] -> 0, x[10] -> 1, x[11] -> 1, 
  a[1] -> 0, a[2] -> 0, a[3] -> 1, a[4] -> 0, a[5] -> 1, a[6] -> 1, 
  a[7] -> 0, a[8] -> 0, a[9] -> 0, a[10] -> 1, a[11] -> 0}} *)
```

Now undo the transformation to get the results in the desired set.

```
2*uu - 1 /. soln

(* Out[263]= {{1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 
  1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1}} *)
```

Comment: Veggy nice ... :)